# Silverlight 3: Any additional transitions available for transitioncontentcontrol?

Tags: silverlight, animation

Transitioncontentcontrol in the silverlight toolkit is awesome especially for non-designers like me. Are there any other transitions availablefor this control? It would be great if they are free, I am also ready to convince my boss if there are any excellent commercial offerings(but free ones are preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the effect described [in this blog post](http://thoughtjelly.blogspot.com/2009/10/restyling-transitions-in-silverlight.html) with the TransitioningContentControl from the Silverlight ToolKit.  It adds a nice bit of eye candy to the application.